# Pressing outside of focused textinput in react native stops click propagation

Tags: react-native

I have some very simple code:

```
<TextInput
  onChangeText={setInputAddress}
  value={inputAddress}
  placeholder="Address or postcode..."
/>

<Button
  title="press"
  onPress={() => {
    Alert.alert("clicked")
  }}
/>
```

The button works fine, and so does the text input, but when I am focussed on the input field, and try to click on the button, it doesn't work. The first click blurs in input field and the second click clicks the button. Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to add `keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"` to the surrounding `ScrollView`.